# How can I open a URL link from within an Excel cell (hyperlink) using a different browser than the default?

Tags: microsoft-excel, command-line, powershell, browser

I have an Excel sheet with URLs that I want to open using a separate browser.
I know how to set the default browser used by different apps using the windows built-ins:

```
cmd /c assoc
cmd /c ftype
```

This would display the (relevant) values as:

```
    
    Value Data  Browser
    -----------------------------------------
    BraveHTML                       Brave
    ChromeHTML                      Chrome
    FirefoxHTML-308046B0AF4A39CB    Firefox
    IE.HTTP                         Internet Explorer
    MSEdgeHTM                       EDGE
    -----------------------------------------
```

You can also access this info with powershell using:

```
# For HTTP
Get-ItemProperty HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice -Name ProgId

# For HTTPS
Get-ItemProperty HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\https\UserChoice -Name ProgId
```

For Excel we have:

```
    Excel.UriLink.16=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\protocolhandler.exe "%1"
    Excelhtmlfile="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE"
```

The problem here is the `protocolhandler.exe` which also handles internal references and who knows what else. For URLs (hyperlinks), it passes them to the default browser.

I want to wrap this to only pass HTTP URL links to the *Brave* browser (for example.)

How can I wrap this command to do the above and with an easy way to revert once I'm done?

---

Not helpful similar questions:

- [How Can I make an excel column of Hyperlinks open in NON default browser](https://superuser.com/questions/1079979/how-can-i-make-an-excel-column-of-hyperlinks-open-in-non-default-browser)
- [Make Excel open some hyperlinks with non-default browser](https://superuser.com/questions/749926/make-excel-open-some-hyperlinks-with-non-default-browser)
- [How can I make a WIN 10 desktop shortcut open a link in Edge, even though Chrome is the default browser?](https://superuser.com/questions/1097333/how-can-i-make-a-win-10-desktop-shortcut-open-a-link-in-edge-even-though-chrome)
- [Open Excel links in other than default browser](https://superuser.com/questions/878712/open-excel-links-in-other-than-default-browser)
- [Make Excel open some hyperlinks with non-default browser](https://superuser.com/questions/749926/make-excel-open-some-hyperlinks-with-non-default-browser)

---

Comment: IMO, I would create a VBA function/UDF that does this. just google "open browser with excel VBA". As an adaptation, you can have the function allow you to choose a browser. As far as easily revert you'll need to further explain this.

Comment: Find the correlated registry key that is passing that `%1` for the HKCU and change that to be `BraveHTML` and see if that does it. So for example something like `Excel.UriLink.16=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\protocolhandler.exe "BraveHTML"` and just hard code it for that specific Windows user profile rather than the whole system and all users if that's what you're trying to accomplish. Should be something as simple or similar as that.

Comment: I tried changing the to use Brave (or FF) instead of protocol handler and it doesn't work. I tried variations of: `cmd /c 'ftype Excel.UriLink.16=C:\Program Files\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\brave.exe "--single-argument" "%1"'`. No go. Why is it not using this? I also tried changing the `ftype ms-excel=...`, still no go. Always goes back to using the *default* browser.

Answer (score 0):

Per [gns100's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1733060/how-can-i-open-a-url-link-from-within-an-excel-cell-hyperlink-using-a-differen/1780744#comment2681322_1733060) you can use a VBA procedure to open URL's in a chosen web browser.

There are browser-specific scripts available on the web however Daniel Pineault's VBA procedure posted on [DEVelopers HUT](https://www.devhut.net/) supports directing URLs to one of 6 browsers: Brave, Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, and Edge.  You can alternate the browser on a per URL basis within thew same document based on the call used.

Source: [A Procedure to Control Them All](https://www.devhut.net/vba-open-a-url-in-firefox-chrome/#:%7E:text=A%20Procedure%20to%20Control%20Them%20All!)

```
Enum BrowserName
    'This Enum is part of Sub OpenURL()
    ' *** If changes are made here, update GetBrowserNameEnumValue()
    iexplore = 1
    firefox = 2
    chrome = 3
    opera = 4
    msedge = 5
    brave = 6
End Enum


'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : OpenURL
' Author    : Daniel Pineault, CARDA Consultants Inc.
' Website   : http://www.cardaconsultants.com
' Purpose   : Open a URL in a browser
' Copyright : The following is release as Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 International
'             (CC BY-SA 4.0) - https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/
' Req'd Refs: Uses Late Binding, so none required
' Dependencies: BrowserName Enum, GetDefaultBrowser(), GetBrowserNameEnumValue()
'
' Input Variables:
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
' sURL      : URL to open
' lBrowser  : Optional, browser to be used to open the URL, if omitted, the system's
'               default browser will be used
'
' Usage:
' ~~~~~~
' Call OpenURL("https://www.google.ca") 'will use the user's default browser
' Call OpenURL("https://www.google.ca", iexplore)
' Call OpenURL("devhut.net", chrome)
' Call OpenURL("msdn.com", firefox)
' Call OpenURL("google.ca", opera)
' Call OpenURL("https://www.google.ca", msedge)
' Call OpenURL("https://www.google.ca", brave)
'
' Revision History:
' Rev       Date(yyyy/mm/dd)        Description
' **************************************************************************************
' 1         2014-11-13              Initial Release
' 2         2018-02-01              Updated Copyright under CC licensing
'                                   Error trapped FireFox not installed
' 3         2018-02-01              Complete revamp of the code to accomodate multiple
'                                   Browser
' 4         2020-04-27              Added Microsoft Edge
'                                   Added Brave
' 5         2020-12-14              Adapted to now have lBrowser as optional and the
'                                   ability to determine the system's default browser
' 6         2022-07-03              Fixed usage examples to match Enum, forgot to do so
'                                   after the last update
'                                   changed msedge sExe to make people happy, not used!
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub OpenURL(ByVal sURL As String, Optional lBrowser As BrowserName)
    Dim oShell                As Object
    Dim sFFExe                As String     'Executable path/filename
    Dim sProgName             As String     'Name of the Executable program
    Dim sExe                  As String     'Executable exe filename
    Dim sCmdLineSwitch        As String     'Command line switch
    Dim sShellCmd             As String     'Shell Command

    On Error GoTo Error_Handler

    'If no browser is specified then use the system's default one
    If lBrowser = 0 Then
        lBrowser = GetBrowserNameEnumValue(GetDefaultBrowser())
    End If

    'Determine the Path to executable
    Select Case lBrowser
        Case 1
            'https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826025(v=vs.85).aspx
            sProgName = "Internet Explorer"
            sExe = "IEXPLORE.EXE"
            sCmdLineSwitch = " "
        Case 2
            'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options#Browser
            sProgName = "Mozilla Firefox"
            sExe = "Firefox.EXE"
            sCmdLineSwitch = " -new-tab "
        Case 3
            sProgName = "Google Chrome"
            sExe = "Chrome.exe"
            sCmdLineSwitch = " -tab "
        Case 4
            'http://www.opera.com/docs/switches/
            sProgName = "Opera"
            sExe = "opera.exe"
            sCmdLineSwitch = " "
        Case 5
            sProgName = "Microsoft Edge"
            sExe = "msedge.exe"
            sCmdLineSwitch = " -tab "
        Case 6
            sProgName = "Brave"
            sExe = "brave.exe"
            sCmdLineSwitch = " -tab "
    End Select

    If lBrowser = 5 Then    'Special case for Edge!  Thank you Microsoft for not following the rules!
        'Build the command
        sShellCmd = "cmd /c """ & "start microsoft-edge:" & sURL & """"
    Else
        Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        sFFExe = oShell.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\" & _
                                "CurrentVersion\App Paths\" & sExe & "\")
        'Parse the returned string
        sFFExe = Replace(sFFExe, Chr(34), "")    'Special case for Opera?!
        'Build the command
        sShellCmd = """" & sFFExe & """" & "" & sCmdLineSwitch & """" & sURL & """"
    End If
    'Open the URL
    Shell sShellCmd, vbHide

Error_Handler_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not oShell Is Nothing Then Set oShell = Nothing
    Exit Sub

Error_Handler:
    If Err.Number = -2147024894 Then
        MsgBox sProgName & " does not appear to be installed on this compter", _
               vbInformation Or vbOKOnly, "Unable to open the requested URL"
    Else
        MsgBox "The following error has occurred" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
               "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
               "Error Source: OpenURL" & vbCrLf & _
               "Error Description: " & Err.Description & _
               Switch(Erl = 0, "", Erl <> 0, vbCrLf & "Line No: " & Erl) _
               , vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "An Error has Occurred!"
    End If
    Resume Error_Handler_Exit
End Sub

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : GetDefaultBrowser
' Author    : Daniel Pineault, CARDA Consultants Inc.
' Website   : http://www.cardaconsultants.com
' Purpose   : Returns the name of the System's Default Web Browser
' Copyright : The following is release as Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 International
'             (CC BY-SA 4.0) - https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/
' Req'd Refs: Uses Late Binding, so none required
'
' Usage:
' ~~~~~~
' GetDefaultBrowser()
'   -> msedge, firefox, brave, iexplore, ...
'
' Revision History:
' Rev       Date(yyyy/mm/dd)        Description
' **************************************************************************************
' 1         2020-12-14              Initial Release
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function GetDefaultBrowser() As String
    Dim oShell                As Object
    Dim sProgId               As String
    Dim sCommand              As String
    Dim aCommand              As Variant

    On Error GoTo Error_Handler

    Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    'Default ProgId
    sProgId = oShell.RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations" & _
                             "\UrlAssociations\https\UserChoice\ProgId")
    'Cross-reference the sProgId to get the exe associated with it
    sCommand = oShell.RegRead("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\" & sProgId & "\shell\open\command\")
    'Parse the returned value to extract just the exe filename
    aCommand = Split(sCommand, Chr(34))
    GetDefaultBrowser = Right(aCommand(1), Len(aCommand(1)) - InStrRev(aCommand(1), "\"))    ' firefox.exe
    GetDefaultBrowser = Left(GetDefaultBrowser, InStr(GetDefaultBrowser, ".") - 1)    'firefox

Error_Handler_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not oShell Is Nothing Then Set oShell = Nothing
    Exit Function

Error_Handler:
    MsgBox "The following error has occurred" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Source: GetDefaultBrowser" & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Description: " & Err.Description & _
           Switch(Erl = 0, "", Erl <> 0, vbCrLf & "Line No: " & Erl) _
           , vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "An Error has Occurred!"
    Resume Error_Handler_Exit
End Function

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : GetBrowserNameEnumValue
' Author    : Daniel Pineault, CARDA Consultants Inc.
' Website   : http://www.cardaconsultants.com
' Purpose   : Convert the returned value from GetDefaultBrowser() into the proper Enum
'               Value.  This is required as VBA offers no way to evaluate a returned
'               value from a function against an Enum, no way to iterate over the string
'               values of an Enum, ...
' Copyright : The following is release as Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 International
'             (CC BY-SA 4.0) - https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/
' Req'd Refs: None required
'
' Usage:
' ~~~~~~
' GetBrowserNameEnumValue(GetDefaultBrowser())
'   -> 1, 2, 3, ...
' GetBrowserNameEnumValue("firefox")
'   -> 2
'
' Revision History:
' Rev       Date(yyyy/mm/dd)        Description
' **************************************************************************************
' 1         2020-12-14              Initial Release
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function GetBrowserNameEnumValue(sInput As String) As Long
    On Error GoTo Error_Handler

    Select Case sInput
        Case "iexplore"
            GetBrowserNameEnumValue = BrowserName.iexplore
        Case "firefox"
            GetBrowserNameEnumValue = BrowserName.firefox
        Case "chrome"
            GetBrowserNameEnumValue = BrowserName.chrome
        Case "opera"
            GetBrowserNameEnumValue = BrowserName.opera
        Case "msedge"
            GetBrowserNameEnumValue = BrowserName.msedge
        Case "brave"
            GetBrowserNameEnumValue = BrowserName.brave
        Case Else
            GetBrowserNameEnumValue = 0
    End Select

Error_Handler_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Function

Error_Handler:
    MsgBox "The following error has occurred" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Source: GetBrowserNameEnumValue" & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Description: " & Err.Description & _
           Switch(Erl = 0, "", Erl <> 0, vbCrLf & "Line No: " & Erl) _
           , vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "An Error has Occurred!"
    Resume Error_Handler_Exit
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on my understanding, Excel's `.xlsx` file format does not support calling external commands. How about an alternative way by directing hyperlinks in Excel to Windows shortcuts (`.lnk` or `.url` files)?

1. Create a Windows shortcut to Brave or Chrome program
   `"C:\Program Files (x86)\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\brave.exe"`
2. Edit the shortcut's "Target" field and append the target URL
   `"C:\Program Files (x86)\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\brave.exe" www.yahoo.com`
3. Create an Excel HYPERLINK formula that points to the full path of the shortcut instead of the URL
   `=HYPERLINK("C:\Path\To\Shortcut\shortcut_name.lnk")`

This method works without any VBA coding and doesn't trigger Antivirus warnings. Also, no security warnings are triggered when opening the Excel file. It is much easier compared to changing the file extension or creating a batch file.

The disadvantage of this approach is you need to separately create and maintain a shortcut file for each URL. Any changes to a URL will require manually editing the associated shortcut's target field.

Comment: Wow that seems like a lot of overhead.

Answer (score -2):

This is fairly simple using Powershell and the ImportExcel module: In my example my spreadsheet has three columns, **`DATE, URL, OTHER_INFO`** and the **URL** column has the links.

Install the [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/7.0.1) module. From the module, use the [Import-Excel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/tree/master/Examples/Import-Excel) cmdlet to read the spreadsheet into a variable and then use a foreach loop to open each link:

```
$excel = Import-Excel -Path "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Temp\test.xlsx"
$brows = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
foreach ($url in $excel.URL){
    Start-Process -FilePath $brows -ArgumentList $url
    #    Write-Host $brows $url  ## TEST
    }

Start-Process -FilePath $brows -ArgumentList $url
```

This will open each link in a new tab in MS's Edge.

If you are unable to use the ImportExcel module, it is more verbose but you can still [access spreadsheet data using the COM objects](https://lazywinadmin.com/2014/03/powershell-read-excel-file-using-com.html)

In the example, replace the path to the browser with the path to whatever browser you want to use.
(Note: I am using the full path to MS's Edge as I don't use the Brave browser.)

This has the added benefit of not needing to revert changes.

Comment: This is not what I asked for. Here you are just reading the excel cells and using it from your shell.